# Change the language on a SmartCast podcast using yahoo pipes?

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes, feedburner

The SmartCast function in FeedBurner is powerful and easy to use, I can do a quick podcast using any blog platform, instead of using other software.
But, it's so dumb to put in the generated XML, without asking, this:

```
</item>
<language>en-us</language>
```

So, iTunes and others podcast indexers thinks that my podcast is in english language. I tried to use yahoo pipes to change that one to "it-it", but, since it is after the last item tag, it is ignored by yahoo pipes.

There is a way to make yahoo pipes to get text from an url and then make a simple string substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way, with an asp.net page

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "iTunes/7.4.1"; 
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
Literal1.Text = htmlText.Replace("<language>en-us</language>", "<language>it-it</language>");
```

by the way, an even better solution is to edit the original feed to include the language, as stated 
[here](http://groups.google.com/group/feedburner-podcasting/browse_thread/thread/60d0da8e5b548e95/75df8b30b5c8c0d3?lnk=gst&q=language#75df8b30b5c8c0d3)

Comment: (i gave the iTunes user agent to avoid being presented with an html page - their "friendly" interface that appears when the feed is opened with a browser)